# Reshaping a dataframe in python into 3D

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to reshape a handwritten character dataset into 3D form so that it can be concatenated with digit recognition dataset. I tried multiple times, but I couldnt figure out how it can be done.

The actual digit recognition dataset has the shape (60000, 28, 28)
The character recognition dataset has the shape (372450, 785) and the first column is target variable. Since excluding first column 28*28=784 there is a possibility that it can be converted to 3D same as digit dataset. Please advice on how this can be done?

I need a shape like (372450,28,28) for the entire dataframe

Thank you in advance

Comment: If it's already a numpy array `arr` (372450, 785) you can just reshape: `arr[:,1::].reshape((372450, 28, 28))`

Comment: Thank you...This worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An array of shape (372450, 785) cannot be made into (372450,28,28) because 28*28 is 784 not 785. But if you meant making a (372450, 784) into (372450,28,28), you could do

```
arr = df.column_name.values
```

will give a numpy array of values from the `column_name` field of the data frame `df`.

Now you can use `reshape()` like

```
arr = arr.reshape(-1,28,28)
```

Now `arr` will be of shape (372450,28,28).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a handwritten character dataset with gray scaled character, you may use following to convert your dataset into 3D,

```
data = data.values.reshape(-1,28,28,1)
```

assuming you have *data* as pandas dataframe.

Last argument is for channels, which is 1 for gray scaled data. If you have RGB images, there are 3 channels and thus we would have converted data into 28x28x3 matrices.