# Python Pandas - Convert 2D df into 3D

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling with pandas transformation, that I would expect to be quite easy. I have the following 2D (10 x 6) data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,6), columns=['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'])
```

I would like to have a corresponding 3D (3 x 2 x 10) data frame, where instead of 1D row from above (A1, ..., B3), there is a 2D new DF:

```
A1 A2 A3
B1 B2 B3
```

Is this achievable in few lines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping a dataframe in python into 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50711786/reshaping-a-dataframe-in-python-into-3d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In earlier versions of *Pandas* there existed *Panel*, i.e. a 3-D array,
but the current version of *Pandas* does not contain it any more.

But you can create a *Numpy* 3-D array:

```
arr = df.values.reshape(3, 2, -1)
```